# Modular arithmetic: 5th powers (mod 11)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Doing a question about modular arithmetic and number theory and I have a mark scheme that doesn't really explain very well.

It say " The 5th powers (mod 11) are 0,1 and 10 ". I can find examples to support this, such as $11^5$ is equal to 0(mod 11), $2^5$ is equal to 10(mod 11).

How do we know that these are the only values that it can take?

Comment: There are only $11$ residue classes $\pmod {11}$, just check them all.

Comment: You know that the multiplicative group has order $10=2\cdot 5$, so all 5th powers of non-zero elements are either 1 or its square root $-1\equiv 10$.

Comment: By Fermat, $\large \bmod 11\!:\ x\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv x^{10}-1 \equiv (x^5-1)(x^5+1)\,\Rightarrow\, x^5\equiv \pm1.\ $ See also [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can write any number as $11n,11n+1,11n+2,11n+3,...11n+10$

This basically means that a number can leave a remainder from  0 to 10  upon division by 11

So if you know the remainders for the fifth powers of  all the numbers upto 11 , you can know which remainders all the numbers will leave upon division by 11.

So ,

$1^5 \equiv 1$ mod $11$

$2^5 \equiv 10$ mod $11$

$3^5 \equiv 1$ mod $11$

$4^5 \equiv 1$ mod $11$

$5^5 \equiv 1$ mod $11$

$6^5 \equiv 10$ mod $11$

$7^5 \equiv 10$ mod $11$

$8^5 \equiv 10$ mod $11$

$9^5 \equiv 1$ mod $11$

$10^5 \equiv 10$ mod $11$

So , as you can see the remainders are only 0 , 1 , 10 , so any number will only leave 0,1,10 as remainder when their fifth power is divided by 11.

Eg) $51^5$ mod $11$

$51 = 44 + 7$ mod $11$

So $51 ^5 $ will leave the remainder of $ 7^ 5$ upon division by 11 ( i.e 10 )

I hope this helps you .

Comment: You can avoid large numbers in your calculation by choosing 11n-5 to 11n+5. And the values 11n-5, 11n-4 to 11n-1 just produce the negatives of the values 11n+5, 11n+4, ..., 11n+1 for odd exponents. It would be identical results for even exponents.